# open local html or pdf file in wpf web-view

Tags: c#, wpf, webview

I am trying to open a local `html` file in web-view in `wpf`. but it doesn't work.it shows a blank white window.

```
PdfWebView.Navigate(@"C:\Users\cWW\Desktop\FINAL YEAR PROJECT\Intelliventory\IntelliVentory\InvoicesPDF\index.html");  

<wpf:WebView Name="PdfWebView"></wpf:WebView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the WebView control from the community toolkit, this does not appear to be possible. It requires NavigateToLocalStreamUri and IUriToStreamResolver, which are available on UWP but don't appear to be available in the WPF version of the control. Looks like displaying local content is out. More information here: https://twitter.com/rickstrahl/status/1004487812169601026?lang=en

Is there any reason WPF's built in WebBrowser control isn't an option?

Comment: hi ! thanks for response ! actually i have also tried built in webbrowser but it doesn't display anything :( because i un-installed only fox pdf reader from my computer. and when it was installed . it worked but pdf shown was extremely rough and destructed !

Answer (score 2):

You have to `load` the file as a string (like you normally get a string from a file) and then call:

```
PdfWebView.NavigateToString(yourString);
```

Comment: That still only gives you a blank webview in a WPF app, unfortunately.

Comment: can you please explain a lil more ?

Comment: 'yourString' is the name of the string, you get from file.

Comment: `PdfWebView.NavigateToString("<html><body><h1>Hello loaded !<h1/><embed src="img.pdf" width="1200px" height="600px" /embed></body></html>");`  

`

Comment: it doesn't work this way if i try to embed !!! only simple text is shown easily ? and idea how to achieve this ?? please

Comment: Well, you can load local html this way.

Comment: @PoulBak local ? isn't what i am doing is local ?

Comment: Yes, but pdf is not available - beacuse that's an add-on and the WebView doesn't support add-ons.

Comment: so ican't just load a local pdf in web-view ?

Comment: No as far as I know.